# How To Model Exception In UML Activity Diagram in Visual Paradigm

Tags: exception, uml, activity-diagram, visual-paradigm

I am a student trying to create an activity diagram for our join chat room use case for our chat module project. I am stuck trying to model an exception wherein when the chat server went down at any step of the join chat basic flow, it will display an error "unable to contact server". I've been trying to do this for 4 hours now. I am trying to model this in Visual Paradigm. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to use ExceptionHandler? I attached a old example made under [Modelio](http://www.modelio.org) (I am not really familiar with visual ....) [image]